Outlook calendar webhook
Hi i am configuring microsoft graph api. i want to configure webhook endpoint of my app, where i will listen to any update happen in outlook calendar. i.e if any event has been created or modified or got deleted in user's outlook calendar i want to listen to that change in my bubble.io app and manage my record in my app.
i went through graph api document but it was confusing for me.
if any guidance is provided will be thankful or any link to the documentation will help too.
cheers
thanks
Roger
Checked this url for subscription for a change but it was confusing for me
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/subscription-post-subscriptions?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

If you can check additional doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/change-notifications-delivery-webhooks?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http What exactly is confusing for you?
